# Msistuff.exe is missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows, url, sdk, windows-installer

I want to create a [URL-based Windows installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/a-url-based-windows-installer-installation-example). I need [Msistuff.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msistuff-exe) to [configure the Setup.exe resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/configuring-the-setup-exe-resources). I have installed the [Windows SDK components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/platform-sdk-components-for-windows-installer-developers). However, I am unable to find Msistuff.exe. Please advise how to get that/find its path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find Msistuff.exe anywhere. The comment from Naticklamb on [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f4569fd0-cdda-47a3-a657-84ee09290fa0/how-to-diagnose-an-url-based-installation-issue-with-a-signed-bootstrapper-setupexe?forum=winformssetup) helped me. I downloaded [this folder](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/sysmgmt/msi/msistuff) and compiled it from VS2019 Developer Command Prompt. After compiling, the Msistuff.exe was created. I installed the following through Visual Studio Installer:

1. `C++ CMake tools for Windows` to get `nmake`
2. `C++ Windows XP Support for VS 2017 (v141) tools [Deprecated]` to get `Win32.mak`